# Transform NSData to int in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I would like to transform NSData to int in Objective-c.

In the following code, "index2" is "15", but "value" is "0".
(NSLog says "15,0".)

To be exact, "value" must be "15".

```
 NSString *index = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSString *index2 = [index stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
 int value = [index2 intValue];
 NSLog(@"%@,%d",index2,value);
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881047/reading-ints-from-nsdata

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply convert nsdata to int try the following.

```
int theInteger;
[completeData getBytes:&theInteger length:sizeof(theInteger)];
```

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7333044/334091) you might need to read the NSData using a range.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I can't. theInteger becomes -272647185. To be exact, it must be 15.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand that NSString index1 is '15', however int index2 is not 15 but 0. Why does [transforming NSString to int] go wrong?