# I am getting hex value in string <0000000a>? How can i convert it into integer in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

First i have to convert Hex but this <> generates an exception when i am trying to convert it to integer

```
NSString *steps =characteristic.value;
int value2= [steps intValue];
```

First i have to removce <>, then convert this hexadecimal string into integer value.

Comment: print out `characteristic` with NSLog to see what you have. What type of object was assigned to value and what is characteristic?

Comment: `characteristic.value` is a `NSData` object. So use `NSData` and `getBytes:length:` Do not use `description`, that's bad habits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform NSData to int in Objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508138/transform-nsdata-to-int-in-objective-c)

Comment: Use `scanHexInt:` from `NSScanner`

Comment: i am getting hexadecimal value <000000ae> which is right, i just want to convert that value from hexadecimal string into integer value

Comment: You should read the `<` with `scanString:intoString:`, and than call `scanHexnt:`.

Comment: "i just want to convert that value from hexadecimal string", it should be a hex NSData, not a hex string. As I said, don't use description. `NSString *steps =characteristic.value;` should throw a warning (putting a `NSData` object into `NSString` object.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSString *strVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int intValue = strVal.intValue;

Answer (score -1):

You have to prefix your string with `0x`:

```
NSString *orig = @"000000ae";
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%@" , orig];
```

to be able to use `NSScanner`:

```
unsigned int outVal;
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
[scanner scanHexInt:&outVal];
```

`outVal` holds your result now.